# Is it possible to mint an NFT directly into another user's Ethereum wallet without their consent?

Tags: nft

Is it possible to mint an NFT directly into another user's Ethereum wallet without their consent, and without any proof that a third party actually created it?

1. Does minting the NFT require the wallet's private key, or just the public one?
2. I am aware that one could always send you an NFT without your consent.  But in that case there would be transaction history showing it came from somewhere else.
3. If another party mints the NFT, even if your wallet is the first owner, is there a way to prove that it wasn't minted by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depending on the minting process defined in the contract.

But in most case yes. These function often provide a "to" address argument. this mean that you can mint an NFT for another address.

No transaction will require your private key.Ever. At least not in the front end since your connecting using Metamask and they provide the connection to the wallet.

Once a NFT is Minted it is sent.

So could still mint an NFT and send it to someone after.

Without anyones consent!

To figure if an NFT was sent to someone rather than mint to someone, look at the from address.

if the from address is 0x0000...
It was minted to you.
If the address is not 0x0000...
The token was transfered to you

You could also see who made the call to that mint function.

Comment: Would the block chain history indicate that it was originally minted by another entity or would my wallet address show up as the first owner of the NFT on the block chain without any trace that it had been minted by another party?

Comment: @user4574 updated my post with that info.

Answer (score 0):

YES, you can send anything to a public address.

NO, you do not need the users private key to do so.